# Email Bodies or Bodys

Tags: grammatical-number, email

I was wondering, how should I refer to the plural of an email body?

Obviously what pops to mind is `bodies`.

However as it's an HTML email that I'm describing, the `body` is actually the content of a `<body></body>` markup element (and it's being written in a moderately technical context), so something more like `"body"s` feels more technically correct.

Is there a standard way to describe these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"bodys" just seems wrong, regardless of context.

I would say that if you are talking about the body of the email, generally, then say "email bodies" for example, as the plural.  If you're talking about the **body tag**, which is a component of the html version of the email, then say **body tags** as the plural.

This page refers to "headers and bodies" when talking about the structure of emails, you could take that as evidence that it's acceptable to do so.

http://ccm.net/contents/117-structure-of-an-email-headers-and-bodies